# How to use JSON Data in another TypeScript function or inside ngOnInit after retrieving Data

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am new to angular and so have a basic question. I have the following on my code

```
public jsonDataResult: any;
private getUrl = "../assets/data_3.json";

getScoreList(){
    this.http.get(this.getUrl).subscribe((res) => {
      this.jsonDataResult = res;
      console.log('Result: ', this.jsonDataResult.length);
    })
  }

  onScoreFetch(){
    this.getScoreList();
    console.log('New Result : ' +  this.jsonDataResult.length)
  }
  

ngOnInit(){
  this.getScoreList();
  this.onScoreFetch();
}
```

I was able to get the data correctly and it shows up on my HTML page but I need to write a function with the data and don't know how to do that. So, I started writing the onScoreFetch function and as a test, I wanted to see if this (this.jsonDataResult.length) works. But it wasn't. It only works inside getScoreList() function, but not inside OnScoreFetch() method/function. Any suggestion?

I tried the following

```
 onScoreFetch(){
    this.getScoreList();
    console.log('New Result : ' +  this.jsonDataResult.length)
  }
```

I was expecting "New Results" to show the length of the "jsonDataResult" . Instead I was getting this:
Error TypeScript: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Comment: You have a race condition. The logging line in `onScoreFetch` is going to execute before the asynchronous operation which populates `jsonDataResult`

Answer (score 0):

```
    public jsonDataResult: any;
    private getUrl = "../assets/data_3.json";
    
    ngOnInit(){
      this.getScoreList();
    } 
    
          getScoreList(){
                this.http.get(this.getUrl).subscribe((res) => 
                  console.log('Result: ', res); 
                  If(res && res.length >0) {
                   this.onScoreFetch(res);
            }
          },
            error()=> { console.log('error message' , error);
     );
   }
        
      onScoreFetch(jsonDataResult){
      console.log('New Result',jsonDataResult);
    }
```

Comment: After completion of the async call (getScoreList) then perform the operation on the data by passing the result to the onScoreFetch function.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, got few more error with this code.  If(res && res.length >0) - Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Object'. Then for onScoreFetch(jsonDataResult){ - Parameter 'jsonDataResult' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: Based on type of response you are receiving from API add the null checks, typechecks &interfaces accordingly. Check Typescript documentation or refer angular.io for reference.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the example:**

```js
public jsonDataResult: any;
private getUrl = "../assets/data_3.json";

getScoreList(){
    this.http.get(this.getUrl)
    .pipe(map((res) => {
      return this.onScoreFetch(res);
    }))
    .subscribe();
  }

  onScoreFetch(res:any){
    let len = res?.length;
    console.log('New Result : ' + len);
    return len;
  }
  

ngOnInit(){
  this.getScoreList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you , but got two errors - First one here " return this.onScoreFetch(res);" it says Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.   . The next error was - return of (len); error says - Cannot find name 'of'. If i remove 'of' the first error still stays and if i remove 'res' errors are gone but the output is undefined.

Comment: Now  please check i have updated the answer

Comment: On console.log , it is showing 'undefined' for len

Comment: OK please check again i have updated again

Comment: This time it worked. Appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.